# Display username in profile page using name stored in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

I want to display username in the profile page after successful login/signup/signup with twitter/signup with google but in my database I have different fields to store user data if he logs in with twitter or google i.e. his data gets stored in `user.twitter.name` if he log in with twitter, and `user.google.name` if he logs in with google and `user.local.name` if he logs in without any services, but, here is the html snippet I am using to display username, but only one of the field is present, then how should I display the username ??

```
<div class="page-header text-center">
    <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor">
        </span> Welcome <% if (user.local.name != undefined) user.local.name 
                        else if (user.google.name != undefined) user.google.name 
                        else if (user.facebook.name != undefined) user.facebook.name %>
    </h1>
    <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Logout</a>
</div>
```

This is what I have implemented so far but it is not working.

What I am trying here is check if any name field is not undefined then use that name to greet the user.

I am new to JavaScript, nodejs and express if anyone can tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write it as follows:

```
<%= user.local.name || user.google.name || user.facebook.name %></h1>
```

In case nothing is found:

```
<%= user.local.name || user.google.name || user.facebook.name || 'User' %></h1>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is there a way to insert function as well in this tag, which does the same thing, but looks smaller, and i can define function at last ?

Comment: yes define function first with same tag, and use it

Comment: also since user.local.name, user.google.name, user.facebook.name and 'User' are variables you forgot to put "=" in the tag such that it becomes




    `<%= user.local.name || user.google.name || user.facebook.name || 'User' %></h1>`
then it works fine